# Cannot write output after reading input in Java

Tags: java, soap

I have received this exception when I call a SOAP app:

> "Cannot write output after reading input"

My implementation is:

```
RL obj = new URL(axaVerificationUrl);
HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection(); 
con.setConnectTimeout(timeoutConnection);
con.setRequestMethod("POST");
con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/soap+xml");
con.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "EligibiliteService");
con.setDoOutput(true);
con.setDoInput(true);
OutputStream objOut = con.getOutputStream();
OutputStreamWriter wr = new OutputStreamWriter(objOut);
wr.write(replacePlaceHolder(request);
wr.flush();
wr.close();
String responseStatus = con.getResponseMessage();
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
String inputLine;
StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();
while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
   response.append(inputLine);
}
in.close();
```

I am getting this exception once I performed exactly this below line:

`OutputStream objOut = con.getOutputStream();`

Before I write the request and get the response code.

Can someone have any experience with this exception?

I am expecting to call a soap API and get successful code.